# How to load a link in safari from a pdf being displayed in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, uiwebview

I am using the Page View Application to show a series of PDF's.  The UIWebView is displaying the PDF's fine, however whenever there is a link that is embedded into the PDF and the user clicks it, it opens the link inside of the UIWebView.  I want it to open said link in safari.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:page ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];


[self.webView loadRequest:request];

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

As You can see i have tried to insert the code to launch it but the BOOL never gets run when stepped through.